R: error passing dataframe to a function that creates ggplot2 plots (data` must be a <data.frame>, not the string "df1")
I need to plot about 30 ggplot2 plots from a few different source dataframes, so I wrote a function to create the plots and a params dataframe to store the plot function parameters. I get this error message when passing parameters from the params dataframe to the function:
data must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by fortify(), not the string "df1"
Here's my code, and I appreciate any suggestions:
#load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

#set up example dataframe:
df1 <- tibble(
  date = seq(ymd('2023-01-01'), ymd('2023-06-30'), by='1 month'),
  A = runif(6, 1, 20),
  B = runif(6, 1, 20),
  C = runif(6, 1, 20)
)

#function to create the plots
gen_plots <- function(df, x, y, title){
  df |> 
    ggplot(
      mapping = aes(x = {{x}}, y = {{y}})
    ) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    #theme_economist() +
    labs(title = {{title}},
         y = "$/MWh",
         x = NULL)
}
  
#test the function--it works:
test_plot <- gen_plots(df1, date, A, "Segment A")

#dataframe with plot parameters (source dataframe, x column, y column, & title):
params <- data.frame(
  df =  c("df1", "df1", "df1"),
  x = c("date", "date", "date"),
  y = c("A", "B", "C"),
  title = c("Segment A", "Segment B", "Segment C")
)

#desired output is a list containing three plots

#code below doesn't work
#gives this error message:
#Error in `pmap()`:
#ℹ In index: 1.
#Caused by error in `fortify()`:
#! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by 
#`fortify()`, not the string "df1".
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

#uncomment line below to see error msg:
#plots <- pmap(params, gen_plots)


The error message is pretty clear, right? Your params dataframe has strings ("df1") for the data.frames, so that is what you are trying to plot. Include the actual dataframes in your params, either by making params a list instead of a data.frame, or by including a list column (df = list(df1, df1, df1)) in the data.frame.

Thanks @Axeman. How do I incorporate the other 3 function parameters? Using lists like this doesn't work:
params_new <- list(df = df1, x = df1$date, y = df1$A, title = "Segment A",
df = df1, x = df1$date, y = df1$B, title = "Segment B",
df = df1, x = df1$date, y = df1$C, title = "Segment C")
plots <- pmap(params_new, gen_plots)
